# libgdx - How can I create Circle class objects using for loop?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating board game and I need to draw circles for players (2-5 players). I can draw them using ShapeRenderer but then I don't have control over circles (change position, radius, etc.). So I need to create 2-5 Circle class object using for loop (I want to do it with for loop). How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try something by yourself?

Comment: Yes I have. I Have created 5 Circle class objects at the start of the game but It is not good because in game can be less than 5 players, so sometimes some objects won't be used.
for(int t=0; t<playersPlaying.getItems().size; t++){
                if(t==0){
                    player1 = new Circle();
                    DrawPlayerTag(player1, playersPlaying.getItems().get(t).playerColor, counterPlayer1);
                }
                else if(t==1){ }

                else if(t==2){
                }
                else if(t==3){ }
                else{ }
            }

Comment: @user7479651 why you needed to create Circle class objects, you can do it without using Circle too and why ShapeRenderer ?

Comment: I want to have circles representing players because it's a game. Can you tell me how can I draw Circle without ShapeRenderer?
I have tried to put Circle inside Stage but I can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Circle is required in view only or it required in model (eg. Collision detection between circles) too.

If view only then take a circular .png image. Create `Sprite` or `Image` object and use that otherwise you can draw Circle using ShapeRenderer.

you can change position using ShapeRender object Use this Actor with scene2d

https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/gdx-utils/blob/master/gdx-utils/src/com/ng/gdxutils/actor/ShapeRendererActor.java

**EDIT**

```
public static Pixmap getPixmapCircle(int radius, Color color, boolean isFilled) {
        Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(2*radius+1, 2*radius+1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        if(isFilled)
            pixmap.fillCircle(radius, radius, radius);
        else
            pixmap.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius);
        pixmap.drawLine(radius, radius, 2*radius, radius);
        Pixmap.setFilter(Pixmap.Filter.NearestNeighbour);
        return pixmap;
}

Texture texture=new Texture(getPixmapCircle(10, Color.RED, true));

Image image=new Image(texture);
or
Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);
```

Comment: It's a board game so there will not be any collision detection between circles. I only have to move them on x and y axis.

Comment: Are you using scene2d ?

Comment: For some things on screen I use it, but for some other not.

Comment: take a circular white .png image then create Sprite or Image object, depends what you want and then move that sprite or Image on board according to requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a circle class and iterate through them with a for-loop. For example:

```
public class MyCirlce{

    private float radius;
    private Vector2 position;

    public MyCircle(float xPos, float yPos, float radius){
         position = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
         this.radius = radius;   
    }

    public void translate(float xAmount, float yAmount){
         position.x += xAmount;
         position.y += yAmount;
    }

    public void changeSizeBy(float changeAmount){
         radius += changeAmount;
    }

    public void render(ShapeRenderer render){
            render.circle(position.x, position.y, radius);
    }


}
```

This will allow you to dynamically change the position of named circles and the size. Also, if you didn't mind using built in things, you can go to their wiki and see that they have a [Circle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Circle.html) object similar to this with extra functionality like a 'Overlaps' method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to use built in Circle, so can I use Circle object in a way you explained in this example?

Comment: Do you want you're own class that will allow extra functionality to the built in Circle class? @user7479651

Comment: I was thinking about that idea but I didn't know how to implement it in my project. If you could show me an example it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw circle whitout using ShapeRenderer
you can draw another object than move them for example I make a snake whit lable
than you can move them

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: for example make a text box whitout editable than you can move them